# How to validate a variable in PHP using standard Yii2 validators without creating a model?

Tags: php, validation, yii, yii2, yii-components

By the book, you suppose to manage post requests with core validators and rules that are described within a model. The problem comes up if you want to use a separate variable elsewhere.

First you get it from the request i.e.

```
$var = \Yii::$app->request->post('var');
```

Then you need to validate it before use. For example, it needs to be an email. Yii2 has a standard validator 'email', but how do I apply it separately?

I would assume something like this:

```
if( !\Yii::$app->coreValidator( $var, $rule ) )
    return $this->error();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Example,

```
$email = 'test@example.com';
$validator = new yii\validators\EmailValidator();

 if($validator->validate($email, $error)) {
  echo 'Email is valid.'; 
 } 
 else {
  echo $error;
 }
```

[Validate Variable Without Model](http://zero-exception.blogspot.in/2014/12/yii2-validate-value-without-model-ad.html)

You can use any validator or make your own validator by extending Validators Class.

Comment: Yep, also just found it accidentally in official documentation: [Ad Hoc Validation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html#ad-hoc-validation)

Answer (score 0):

You can create simple validator

```
namespace app\components;
use yii\validators\Validator;

class CountryValidator extends Validator
{

    public function validateAttribute($model, $attribute)
    {
        if (!in_array($model->$attribute, ['USA', 'Web'])) {
            $this->addError($model, $attribute, 'The country must be either "USA" or "Web".');
        }
    }
}
```

This is a link of offical doucmentation [Yii2](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html)